# Land border crossing in Italy

Tags: italy, borders, proof-provenance-of-funds

I kinda had some problems with Croatian border police last days, they said I did not enough cash money(100€)to enter Croatia, but I did handle with some way and now I’m Slovenia. Now I’m planning to go to Italy from Slovenia by train.

My quesiton is would border police in Italy want to see cash money in my pocket? If they want, how much cash I need to carry with me? (I’ve done hostel reservations, no problem with that)

(I’m from Turkey btw, that’s why border cops are not being very nice to me:P)

Comment: Could you go to your other question and either post your own answer explaining what happened and/or add a comment to mine (if you followed my advice and it was or wasn't helpful)? Also please either accept my answer or add your own and accept that. Questions and answers are more useful to future readers when the asker if the question gives feedback on the quality of the answers.  Thank you.

Comment: If you refer to Annex25 of the Visa Code Handbook which i linked to in your previous question, you’ll see that the required means of support for Italy depends on the length of stay. For 1-5 days for example, it’s €269.9

Comment: @Traveller but someone crossing from Slovenia to Italy is not going to be evaluated against that requirement; the evaluation of the means of support should have happened on entry into Slovenia (or, more generally, whichever country was the point of entry into the Schengen area).

Comment: @Phoog Thanks, I’d not understood it like that, I assumed it was per country.

Comment: @Traveller the magnitude of the required means of support is indeed determined by each country, but the evaluation of means occurs only when someone is applying for a visa (if one is needed) and at the external Schengen border when the officer is deciding whether to admit him or her.  Presumably they're supposed to take the itinerary into account (so an officer at a German airport should consider the Italian amounts for someone who's en route to Italy), but I don't know how that works in practice.

Answer (score 5):

Slovenia and Italy are both in the Schengen zone.  You may be subjected to a "random" document check, but there is otherwise no systematic border control.  I suppose it's possible that the random check would go beyond documents and look at other conditions of entry, but in my experience, such checks are limited to documents.